# how to properly split a string in php that contains HTML entities

Tags: php

I need to split a very long string every 100 characters. The string includes HTML entities. I'm using the function `str_split_unicode()` but the result is not what I need.

My original string includes HTML entities, example `&#47 ;` instead of `/`.

My php code is the following:

```
$string_stripped = str_split_unicode($string, 100);
```

I then access to the first 100 characters with `$string_stripped[0]`, characters from 101 to 200 with `$string_stripped[1]` and so on.

The problem is that `&#47 ;` will be counted by `str_split_unicode` as one character instead of 5 characters. This result in a output string longer than 100 characters. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $newText = wordwrap($string, 100, "\n");
    string_stripped = explode("\n", $newText);
?>
```

Read more about [wordwrap()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)
Read more about [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)